# Tkinter Python Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

quero fazer com que o botão btnteste modifique o texto na label(root), não estou conseguindo fazer

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+600+200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Testando")
root["bg"]="orange"

teste = "Vamos testar"

espaco1 = Label(root, font=("arial", 20), text=teste, bg="yellow", 
fg="black")
espaco1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

dadosf = Frame(root, width=800, height=400, bg="pink")
dadosf.pack(side=TOP)

def codados():

    opt1 = Toplevel(root)
    opt1.geometry("400x200+800+300")
    opt1.resizable(False, False)
    opt1.title("Top")
    opt1["bg"] = "pink"

    espacof = Frame(opt1, width=200, height=100, bg="yellow")
    espacof.pack(side=TOP)

    def btnteste():
        global teste
        teste = "Outro Texto"

    global teste
    btn = Button(espacof, text=teste, bg="black", fg="white", 
    command=btnteste)
    btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

dados = Button(dadosf, text=teste, bg="purple", fg="yellow", 
command=codados)
dados.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Alterei minha resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que existem duas variáveis com o mesmo nome `teste`. Uma criada no escopo do módulo, e outra local criada dentro do escopo da função.

Você está atribuindo um valor à variável dentro da função, porém, isso causa a criação de uma nova variável de escopo local, enquanto a outra variável de módulo continua inalterada.

Uma forma relativamente simples de solucionar é declarar a variável como `global` dentro da função:

```
def codados(): 
    global teste
    # .... restante da funcao permanece normal ....
```

Com essa declaração a variável externa será reatribuída a partir de dentro da função.

---

EDIT: Se na verdade você quer trocar é o texto do botão, não é preciso alterar a variável `teste`. Porém é necessário criar um objeto do tipo `StringVar()` do `tkinter`:

```
#....
sv = StringVar()
sv.set("Vamos testar")

def btnteste():
    sv.set("Outro Texto")

btn = Button(espacof, textvariable=sv, bg="black", fg="white", command=btnteste)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
#....
```